# Writing a sorting algorithm to sort CustomInteger objects

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to make a sorting algorithm to sort the CustomInteger objects in **ascending** order. The sorting method should utilize the goodSwap method that I've written. At some point, I had managed to find some interesting articles and code samples to do the sorting for integers but doesn't work for my problem. Here is the links I done research for my problem:

1. http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-to-bubble-sort
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/#sorting
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUOyKSZScW0
4. http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/quick-sort/
5. http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/

Here's my code: 
CustomInteger.java

```
 /**
  * @author AbduMuhaimin
  * @since 16/12/2015
  * Java Good Swap algorithm
  **/
//class CustomInteger

class CustomInteger {
    private int value;

    public CustomInteger(int i) {
        this.value = i;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public static void goodSwap(CustomInteger a, CustomInteger b) {
        CustomInteger z = new CustomInteger(a.getValue());
        a.setValue(b.getValue());
        b.setValue(z.getValue());
    }
    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //before swapping
        CustomInteger a = new CustomInteger(10);
        CustomInteger b = new CustomInteger(5);
        System.out.println("Before swapping\n");
        System.out.println("Value of a: " + a.getValue() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Value of b: " + b.getValue() + "\n");

        //after swapping
        goodSwap(a,b);
        System.out.println("After swapping\n");
        System.out.println("Value of a: " + a.getValue() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Value of b: " + b.getValue() + "\n");
    }

}
```

How to make the sorting algorithm and what type of sort do I have to use? Is it bubble, merge or quick sort? I am still new at sorting stuffs in Java :)

Comment: You can use any sorting algorithm you want. I suggest you start with the easiest one: Insertion Sort.

Comment: @Manu: can you give me an example of it or just the link - it will help :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: Your links have all the things you need to know, why those don't work for your problem?

Comment: @PhamTrung: It doesn't show how to sort a number that are being swapped. (Doesn't show how to sort before the swap and after the swap)

Comment: So did you mean that after getting a sorted array, you will swap some elements, thus we need to sort them one more time?

Comment: @PhamTrung: no. I will have to swap some elements and sort it. The sorting method must utilize the goodSwap method :)

Comment: `goodSwap` and normal swap in those links have no difference. swap some elements or not, after the sort, you will get a sorted array. For example array {1, 3, 2} -> swap to {2 , 3, 1} -> sort {1, 2, 3}, you will get similar result without any swap.

Comment: @PhamTrung: so that means, `goodSwap` is no different than the normal swap, isn't it?

Comment: why is the down vote? Is there any mistakes in this question?

Comment: That what I understand after reading your implementation. Normal swap : `int tmp = a.getValue(); a.setValue(b.getValue()); b.setValue(tmp);` . `goodSwap` is similar, except you use a `CustomInteger tmp` instead of `int tmp`.

Comment: @PhamTrung so, how to sort the swapped elements? Can you give me some extra links - it will totally help me in solving this problem :)

Comment: swapped or not, it doesn't effect the final result, sorted version of {1 , 3, 2} and {2 , 3 , 1 } ... are all {1, 2, 3}. All you need are already in your question.

Comment: @PhamTrung: oh..i see :D thanks anyway my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selection sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

```
    CustomInteger[] vec = new CustomInteger[]{new CustomInteger(5), new CustomInteger(1), new CustomInteger(2), new CustomInteger(4), new CustomInteger(5), new CustomInteger(2)};

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length - 1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < vec.length; j++) {
            if (vec[j].getValue() < vec[min].getValue()) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min != i) {
            goodSwap(vec[i], vec[min]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(vec[i].getValue() + " ");
    }
```

Comment: @AbduMuhaimin no it doesn't. just throw it in your main method

Comment: It did. it gave me an error at the line CustomInteger[] vec = new ...

The error is: "Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token"

Comment: @AbduMuhaimin most probably you missed something

Comment: nope. I copied the code entirely in Eclipse. Maybe just the Eclipse bug, I suppose or is it the code? I will check to make sure the code is perfect :) thanks for the help my friend